# Magento redirect issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two store views Magento 1.9

http://www.1guru4you.com/

http://www.1guru4you.com/gr

If i type in the URL field http://www.1guru4you.com/gr , it redirects me to http://www.1guru4you.com/.

This behavior is a problem for me. How can i solve it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set Configuration as per below steps
1)Go to Admin 
2)System Configuration
3)General Web
4)URL Option
5) Add store code to url => YES

Comment: Thank you i enabled global, but the issue still persist

Comment: Please clear cache and reindex

Comment: If i type in URL field www.1guru4you.com/gr it works. But if i enter it without www. then it redirects to http://www.1guru4you.com/ again